# Javascript regex to find expression in a line then append to the end of that line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am busy parsing a text log to HTML and I am replacing tabs with HTML bullet tags

I need a regular expression to identify the beginning of a line and then append something to the end of it. eg:

```
config system accprofile
    edit "Number 1"
        set mntgrp read-write
    edit "read-only"
        set mntgrp read

config system 2
    edit "Number 2"
        set mntgrp read-write
    edit "read-only"
        set mntgrp read
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
<ul>
    <li>config system accprofile</li>
        <ul>
        <li>edit "Number 1"</li>
            <ul>
            <li>set mntgrp read-write</li>
            </ul>
        <li>edit "read-only"</li>
            <ul>    
            <li>set mntgrp read</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    <li>config system 2</li>
        <ul>
        <li>edit "Number 2"</li>
            <ul>
            <li>set mntgrp read-write</li>
            </ul>
        <li>edit "read-only"</li>
            <ul>
            <li>set mntgrp read</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

I can identify the front of each row by searching for 'config' but I then need to append `\n\t<ul>` to the end of the line.

How can I do this?

Comment: you are using vanilla js?

Comment: Hi, I am using node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

```js
function myReplaceMethod (text) {
    console.clear();
    text = text.replace(/^(?:\t| {4}){2}(?!\s)(.*)/gm, '\t\t\t<li>$1</li>');
    text = text.replace(/^(?:\t| {4}){1}(?!\s)(.*)/gm, '\t\t<li>$1</li>\n\t\t\t<ul>');
    text = text.replace(/^(?!\s)(.*)/gm, '\t<li>$1</li>\n\t\t<ul>');
    text = text.replace(/(\n(\s*)<li>.*)(?:\n(?!\2\s)|(?![\s\S]))/gm, '$1\n$2</ul>\n');
    text = text.replace(/^/, '<ul>\n');
    text = text.replace(/$/, '\n</ul>');
    text = text.replace(/(\n(\s*)(?:\t| {4})<\/ul>\n)(?=\n)/gm, '$1$2</ul>');
    return text;
};

// ---

var string =
    'config system accprofile\n' +
    '    edit "Number 1"\n' +
    '        set mntgrp read-write\n' +
    '    edit "read-only"\n' +
    '        set mntgrp read\n' +
    '\n' +
    'config system 2\n' +
    '    edit "Number 2"\n' +
    '        set mntgrp read-write\n' +
    '    edit "read-only"\n' +
    '        set mntgrp read';

var output = myReplaceMethod(string);

console.log(output);
```